# Is there any standard N-sphere that has non-trivial first Pontryagin class?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I am wondering if there is a standard $N$-sphere that has non-trivial first Pontryagin class on its tangent bundle $TS^n$and frame bundle $FS^n$?

I know that only $S^4$ has non-trivial $H^4(S^n, R)$ cohomology class, while locally I write the first Pontryagin class on $TS^n$ as $Tr(R^2)$, where $R$ is curvature of $S^n$, is trivially zero. Does it mean all sphere have trivial first Pontryagin class?

Comment: The characteristic classes of the tangent bundle and the frame bundle are the same by definition (at least according to one definition).

Answer (score 6):

All positive characteristic classes vanish for the tangent bundles of standard spheres, as they are *stably trivial*. That is, $TS^{n} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ is a trivial bundle. One might see it by looking at the standard embedding $S^{n} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, where we have

$\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \simeq T\mathbb{R}^{n+1} |_{S^{n}} \simeq N_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1} / S^{n+1}} \oplus TS^{n+1}$.

Now, the normal bundle is trivial as one can orient it consistently in either the "zero-pointing" or "infinity-pointing" directions in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. To see that this implies your result, recall that the Pontryagin classes are the Chern classes of complexification and we have

$\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \simeq (TS^{n} \oplus \mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathbb{C} \simeq (TS^{n} \otimes \mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathbb{C}$.

The Whitney formula implies that

$1 = c(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}) = c((TS^{n} \otimes \mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathbb{C}) \simeq c(TS^{n} \otimes \mathbb{C}) * c(\mathbb{C}) = c(TS^{n} \otimes \mathbb{C})$,

so all the Pontryagin classes vanish.

Comment: Excuse me, may you clarify please, (1) for this relation, $$\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \simeq (TS^{n} \oplus \mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathbb{C'} \simeq (TS^{n} \otimes \mathbb{C'}) \oplus \mathbb{C'},$$
what is the real dimension of $\mathbb{C'}$? Is that just 2-real dimensions? But if so, the left-hand-side (LHS) has $2(n+1)$-real dimensions, while RHS has only $n+2$-real dimension? Or do you take $TS^n$ with $2n$-real dimensions?

Comment: (2) Do you mean to claim that **a standard $N$-sphere that has non-trivial first Pontryagin class on both its tangent bundle $TS^n$ and frame bundle $FS^n$?**

Comment: why does 'orient it consistently in either the "zero-pointing"' say the normal bundle is trivial? vs the line bundle that all lines are parallel in $R^{n+1}$? What does it mean by "trivial" for a real line bundle?

Answer (score 4):

Since $p_1(S^n) \in H^4(S^n; \Bbb Z)$, the only possible sphere $S^n$ with $p_1(S^n) \neq 0$ is $S^4$. Now $S^4$ can be considered as the quaternionic projective line $\Bbb H P^1$. There is a general formula for the total Pontryagin class of $\Bbb H P^m$:
$$p(\Bbb H P^m) = \frac{(1+u)^{2m+2}}{1+4u},$$
where $u$ is a generator of $H^4(\Bbb H P^m; \Bbb Z)$ (see Exercise 20-A of Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*). It follows that
$$p_1(\Bbb H P^m) = (2m-2)u.$$
Therefore
$$p_1(S^4) = p_1(\Bbb H P^1) = 0,$$
and all (standard) spheres have trivial first Pontryagin class.

Comment: Thanks for this instructive answer! So then what about the $p_1$ on Frame Bundle of $S^N$? They are all trivial as well?