# Characteristic classes detect $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

We know that the Stieffel Whitney class of tangent bundle of $M$ can be computed and integrated over the $M$ to get a nontrivial integration
If I understand correctly,
$$
\int_{M=\mathbb{RP}^2} w_1(M)^2=1
$$
$$
\int_{M=\mathbb{RP}^4} w_1(M)^4=1
$$

My question is that are there some proper characteristic classes, say $A$ and $B$ detect the $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2$?
$$
\int_{M=\mathbb{CP}^1} (\text{characteristic classes }A)=1
$$
$$
\int_{M=\mathbb{CP}^2} (\text{characteristic classes } B)=1
$$

Comment: You want Chern classes. I’m not sure what you mean by “detect” though.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, we can also use $\int_{M=\mathbb{CP}^2} w_2^2(M)=1$. Isn't it?

Comment: Also $c_j = w_{2 j}  (mod 2)$ on a complex manifold, so naively, $\int_{CP^1} c_1(M) =\int_{CP^1} w_2(M) = 1$, $\int_{CP^2} w_2(M)^2 = 1$. Yes?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, Sorry $\int_{M=\mathbb{CP}^1} c_1(M)=2$.

Comment: When you integrate your characteristic classes you are implicitly using real coefficients. Without further comment, your integrals over the Stiefel-Whitney classes - which are mod 2 characteristic classes - don't really make sense.

Comment: Moreover, you have $c_1(\mathbb{C}P^1)=2\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^1;\mathbb{Z})$, $c_1(\mathbb{C}P^2)=3\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{Z})$ and $c_2(\mathbb{C}P^2)=3\in H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2)$. Thus $w_2(\mathbb{C}P^1)=1\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^1;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, $w_2(\mathbb{C}P^2)=1\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $p_1(\mathbb{C}P^2)=3\in H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Since you are using real coefficients, just define a characteristic class $c_2'=\frac{1}{3}c_2$ to get $c_2'(\mathbb{C}P^2)=1\in H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{R})$ to get what you want.

Comment: How can one show that w2(ℂP1)=1∈H2(ℂP1;ℤ2) and w2(ℂP2)=1∈H2(ℂP2;ℤ2)? Where can one find this Ref?

Comment: @Tyrone, isnt that $w_2(CP^1)=0$ due to $c_1(CP^1)$ mod 2 $=w_2(CP^1)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out my error. That is the correct statement. I remember getting my $\mathbb{C}P^1$s and $\mathbb{C}P^2$s mixed up in the wall of mathjax  whilst typing that.

Comment: @Tyrone, do you mind to re-type the correct statements again? (I am confused by the overall picture) Or update them as an answer please? Thanks please!

Comment: @Tyrone, can you please update as an answer?

Comment: How about $p_1(\mathbb{RP}^4) ?$

Comment: Maybe this is correct answer for $p_1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513570/is-there-any-standard-n-sphere-that-has-non-trivial-first-pontryagin-class ?